# Utility to create symlinks for all executables in the Start Menu?

Tags: windows, path, symbolic-link, start-menu

It's really annoying in Windows that if you want to run about any third-party program from the command line, you either have to use its full path or manually add its containing directory to `PATH`.

Is there a utility that scans all entries in the Start Menu, and creates a symlink to each of the executables in a certain directory, so that I only have to add this one directory to `PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this functionality with a Python script.

This is surprisingly difficult to make it right though:

1. Shortcuts work in the shell (`Run Dialog`, double clicking the file, etc), but not in `Cmd`.
2. Symlinks work in `Cmd`, but not in the shell.
3. Hardlinks work in both, but can't cross partition boundaries.

I ended up using shortcuts. On the command line I have to type `program.lnk` for it to work, and this is on Windows 7, it doesn't work in XP.

Answer (score 0):

First, I dont know a utility to automate this process.

Likewise your own answer you only have to create links in one special directory and include this to the `PATH`. But to really get it working in commandline, run-dialog and with doubleclicking you need to use Batch-Scripts:

To start file D:\Inkscape\inkscape.exe

> @"D:\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" %*

Save that in a file named `inkscape.cmd` in this special directory. Then inkscpae is accessable from within the commandline or the run-dialog. All arguments ar piped to the original file.

This works best for CLI programms (yes, inkscape has an CLI) because a cmd.exe process starts to start the wantet programm and doesnt exit until the termination of the started program. For GUI programms it is better to use:

> @START "D:\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" %*

Then the cmd.exe process exits after starting the program. All arguments are piped, too.

I use this for an flashdrive installation of LaTeX and for some simple unix-commands in windows (7/64; xp/32). And it works well.